# Error: The following exception occurred creating the MEF composition container

Tags: silverlight, code-generation, wcf-ria-services

I have RIA Services application

And I got this warning

> The following exception occurred creating the MEF composition container:
>       Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>       The default code generator will be used.

Why is it?

Comment: Can you `Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property` and share the details?

Comment: @EdChapel  Sorry, I cannot. I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: if you are registering your domaincontexts in the container, you need to add a `new InjectionConstructor()` . this is because the Proxy of the DomainService, your domaincontext has 3 constructors and it cannot resolve an instance without knowing what constructor to use.

Comment: @Rikkos Could it be because I reference to some dlls under my project? I use  http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Peretz I cant tell. I either need to look at it or you need to give me a more details about your structore of your project and what dlls you have. I'll have a look at it tomorrow together with this post http://forums.silverlight.net/t/228490.aspx/2/10 . Does that also state your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I accidentally added a reference to my generated entities in the WEB project (the web project that hosts your Silverlight App that is connected through RIA Services).

To solve this, remove the reference to the entities in the web project (web project that has a page hosting your silverlight app).  Once the reference is gone, the warning is removed.

I haven't looked into the reasoning for why the warning is thrown...but in my case, removing the reference resolved the warning.

Comment: Can you be more specific here? Do you mean a project/dll reference or do you mean some code is included that shouldn't be?